# Security Design for iOS App

Tags: ios, web-services, security, post

I'm having trouble determining what the best approach is for the following scenario.

- My application POST's to my web service.
- POST URL includes several parameters, including device info + a shared secret
- The device is stored in my database **IF** the shared secret is **correct**

At the moment, this shared secret is hard-coded in the app and the connection to my web service is over SSL.

This obviously limits people from finding out the shared secret and abusing my web service.

However this approach isn't as secure as I'd like, due to the possibility of decoding my app etc and getting the secret.

Is there a better way of doing this, as opposed to the shared secret approach?

Comment: When you allow people to download your app and execute it, you're giving them the object code.  Consequently, no solution is going to be completely secure, since you have to put the "secret" into your program in some way or the program will not function.

Answer (score 1):

With local keys almost every security approach can be leaked by somebody somehow. This does of course **not** mean that we do not need to put any effort in at all. 
If people download your app the can possible further investigate the code by ***[reengineering and or refactoring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reengineering_%28software%29)***

However, if there is no other way than putting the secret key within your apps binary, you're left with a (**weaker**) alternative often called ***[security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity)***.

There are many ways to do this and you can probably find a lot of discussion on the internet about this topic so here are just some ideas:

- Split the key to multiple classes and throughout your code
- Disguise your key as string which will could be used in a normal way within your app
- Hash some data or code segments on startup and include them in your key
- Use all of the methods named above together

There are even some frameworks out there like **[UAObfuscatedString](https://github.com/UrbanApps/UAObfuscatedString)** which might help you implementing your logic.

Keep in mind, the best way is always to `not hardcode a secret key within your apps binary` but somehow "load" the secret from your server who e.g. calculates the key…

Comment: Thanks Alexander. In relation to your last comment - If I don't store the secret key within the apps binary, how else do I know that the person accessing my API is a legitimate device that has installed my app....or a spoofer using something like CURL..? If the secret can be retrieved from the server, then potentially any device/pc/user can get the API key...

Comment: You could e.g. use a user registration and, after a user has managed this successfully, share a secret with him (the app). The app stores the secret within the keychain. When calling your "secure api" the app could e.g. put the secret key from the keychain in an authorization header which would include the device identifier and some other properties – have a look at the amazon webservice concept which uses hmac1_sha: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html